# Does Snowflake Storage Integration Support Multiple Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowflake Storage Integration Support Multiple Azure Storage Account?
In the documentation(https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html), it is specified like below.

```
create storage integration azure_int
type = external_stage
storage_provider = azure
enabled = true
azure_tenant_id = 'a123b4c5-1234-123a-a12b-1a23b45678c9'
storage_allowed_locations = ('azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/mypath1/', 'azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2/mypath2/')
storage_blocked_locations = ('azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/mypath1/sensitivedata/', 'azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2/mypath2/sensitivedata/');
```

My question is "Does it support like below?"

```
create storage integration azure_int
type = external_stage
storage_provider = azure
enabled = true azure_tenant_id = 'a123b4c5-1234-123a-a12b-1a23b45678c9'
storage_allowed_locations = ('azure://myaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/mypath1/', 'azure://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2/mypath2/')
storage_blocked_locations = ('azure://myaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/mypath1/sensitivedata/', 'azure://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2/mypath2/sensitivedata/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be set up for multiple accounts in the storage integrations.
Please note that for the cross tenant vnet rules it needs to be in the same region as their Snowflake Account or the [paired region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview) with Azure.